# jQuery select only children until specific class

Tags: jquery, dom, selector, parent

I have some recursive HTML in the following tree structure:

```
div.item
 div.content
  input
  div.container
   div.item
    div.content
     input
     div.container
      div.item
       etc...
```

Here's a jsfiddle with a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/HWHRZ/

I also have a objects with jQuery references to each of the `.item` divs.

What I want to do is, for any specific `.item`, select only the inputs immediately underneath, excluding those in any deeper `.container` or `.item` elements.

To make things more complicated, not every `.item` has an identical layout with regards to the inputs. Sometimes inputs may be in other `div` elements, so selecting them with a simple `.find('> .content :input')` won't always work.

I have found a solution, but it's inefficient with large trees and not at all elegant: 
`$(':input', $item).not($('.container :input', $item)).toggleClass('changed');`
(`$item` is a reference I keep in an object). This solution works as it should, but is way too inefficient for any sufficiently large tree structure, is the `not()` would have to process a lot of node.

In short: I need to select specific child nodes that are NOT within specific other child nodes.

Does anybody know of a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: So, you've got unclosed `div` tags, no self-closing slashes on most (if not all) `input` tags, unclosed `select` elements, multiple elements with the same `id`...

Comment: can you post a jsfiddle of your html that really help

Comment: @DavidThomas. Yes. You'd almost think it was just meant to show the tree structure instead of actual HTML. I'll set up a jsfiddle to help you understand better.

Comment: @DavidThomas “Self-closing slashes” are only required in XHTML, not HTML.

Comment: I've posted a jsfiddle example to demonstrate the issue. It also includes a solution, but I'm looking for a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think

```
$.each($($(".item")[0]).children(".changed"),function(){
$(this).removeClass("changed")
})
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

This function might help:

```
$.fn.childrenUntil = function( selector, result)
{
    result = typeof result !== 'undefined' ? result : new $();
    this.children().each( function(){
       var thisObject = $( this );
        if( thisObject.is( selector ) ) 
            result.push( this );
        else
            thisObject.childrenUntil( selector, result );
    });
    return result;
}
```

It traverses the tree until it encounters the selector.